# How to call a variable by a string value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a data set as

```
var data1 = {values:[
  { X: "33", Y: 12 },
  ....
  ]};
var data2 = { values:[
  { X: "Jan", Y: 2 },
  ...
  ]};
```

I want to load appropriate data set by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function(){
  var data = $(this).val() // the value will be data1 or data2
           // how can I make the data a JSON equal to data1 or data2 instead of
           // assigning the static value of $(this).val() to it.
  }
});
```

How can I create the `var data` from the static value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.

Have `data1`, `data2` as properties of an object, and use the square bracket member operator to access them.

```
var dataset = {

    data1: {
        values: [{
            X: "33",
            Y: 12
        }, ....]
    }
    data2: {
        values: [{
            X: "Jan",
            Y: 2
        }, ...]
    };
}
```

---

```
var data = dataset[$(this).val()]
```

---

Although if your `data1` and `data2` are global variables, you could access them the same way from the `window` object.

```
var data = window[$(this).val()]
```

But an object like `dataset` is still nicer than a bunch of globals.